# Find real constants such that the following functions are solutions of the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this question (without a solution) which I'm finding it hard to solve:

Find the real constants $a,b,c,d,r,st,p,q$ such that the four functions
$\sin(x), \sin(2x), \sin(3x), \sin(4x)$

are solutions of the function
$y^{(8)}+ay^{(7)}+by^{(6)}+cy^{(5)}+dy^{(4)}+ry^{(3)}+sy''+ty'+py=q$

I tried to plug in the solutions, so as $\cos(x), \cos(2x), \cos(3x)$ and $\cos(4x)$, and evaluate at $x=0, x=\frac{\pi}{2}, x=\pi$ and $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ but I ended up with a 12-functions system that isn't giving me a coherent solution.

Comment: Your approach is sound and probably would work if you were very determined but likely to be painful and easy to make a mistake. I think the easier trick is to just write down the characteristic equation, which is a degree 8 polynomial, and choose coefficients such that $i,2i,3i,4i$ are roots.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis Thank you, It was much shorter this way (and less prone to mistakes)